# CRUD Operation using NAPA in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am completely new to SharePoint development.
I am trying to create an app for basic CRUD operation using NAPA.
I took the reference from http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/.

There are some basic get commands in REST.
I am using Get All List Items From a Single List (where url is like: `http://UsersrverName/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘listname’)/items`)

Now for getting list items based on ODATA Query, the function is:

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

here, as per function arguments, I have assigned the value for **url** and  **listname**, **query** is blank as I am selecting all items, and I have no idea what to assign for **complete** and **failure**.

So my main concern is the arguments to be passed in the function getListItems().

Kindly help. and if there is any other alternative (without using REST), then please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  `I am not getting the url concept there` is not a great way to ask questions.  What exactly are you trying to do, what have you tried, and why didn't what you tried work?

Comment: @Philip Pittle i have edited the question. Please see

Comment: Much nicer.  What happens when you call `getListItmes("http://UsersrverName/site", "listname")`

Answer (score 1):

Basically `complete` and `failure` arguments are *function callbacks*. The following example demonstrates how to call the specified function:

```
var webUrl = 'http://intranet.contoso.com';
var listTitle = 'Documents';
var queryOptions = '';
getListItems(webUrl,listTitle ,queryOptions,
   function(data){ //success callback function
       for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
         var item = data.d.results[i]; 
         console.log(item.Title);
       }  
   },
   function(error){  //error callback function
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
);
```

**Key points:**

SharePoint REST endpoint `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items` returns JSON object in the following format:

(for `Documents` library)

[image]

---

Another approach that is commonly used and was introduced in jQuery 1.5 is based on the [CommonJS Promises/A design](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A):

> `jQuery.Deferred()` provides flexible ways to provide multiple
>   callbacks, and these callbacks can be invoked regardless of whether
>   the original callback dispatch has already occurred

The same example that demonstrates how to utilize `jQuery.Deferred()` object:

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','')
.done(function(data)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
         var item = data.d.results[i]; 
         console.log(item.Title);
    }  
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```